# I cannot use console.log, console.warn, console.error in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logging, browser

I'm using VueJS for development and recently I started to notice that I cannot use console.log or console.warn in browser instead I got this message
`Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform`

But if I use console.log directly in the browser it work fine, it just doesn't throw data log from my project.

There're a bunch of text describe it as well but I don't how to fixed it.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19kgu.png)

Have anyone facing the same situation and know how to fixed it? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to it. Turn out I run `npm run dev` instead of `npm run watch`. I'm not sure how this work but when I change to use `npm run watch` it works fine.